# Getting lat and long value from places google search

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to access lat and long of after completing a search on google maps and use them to make a JSON call (https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE - https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2). I have the following code:

```
var animateLeft = 'animateDisplayInfo',
    mainWrapper = $('.displayInfo');

var weatherAPP = {

    generateMap: function(){

        var style = [{"featureType":"landscape","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":65},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":51},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":30},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":40},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"transit","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.province","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-100}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#ffff00"},{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-97}]}];

        var mapHolder = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5072, 0.1275),
            zoom:6,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles: style
        };

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapHolder, mapOptions);

    },

    slideToSearch:function(){
        mainWrapper.addClass(animateLeft);
    },

    slideToCloseSearch:function(){
        weatherAPP.generateRainVisualEffect();
        mainWrapper.removeClass(animateLeft);
    },

    searchCity:function(){

        var map = this.map,
            markers = [],
            input = document.getElementById('pac-input'),
            dataTable;

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {

            var places = searchBox.getPlaces(),
                apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                url = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/',
                lati = places[0].geometry.location.D,
                longi = places[0].geometry.location.k,
                data,
                city = $('.city'),
                summary = $('.summary');

                console.log(places[0].geometry.viewport.N.N);

       //      $.getJSON(url + apiKey + "/" + lati + "," + longi + "?callback=?", function(data) {


            if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
                marker.setMap(null);
            }

            // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
                var image = {
                    url: 'pin.png'
                };

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: image,
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location
                });

                markers.push(marker);

                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }

            map.fitBounds(bounds);

        }); // places_changed

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
        // current map's viewport.
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
            map.setZoom(6);
            var bounds = map.getBounds();
            searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
        });

    },

    generateRainVisualEffect: function(){
        $('.eq').delay(500).fadeIn();
        function fluctuate(bar) {
            var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150) + 1;
            if(height <= 15){
                $('.eq').css('margin-top', '-22px');
            }
            //Animate the equalizer bar repeatedly
            bar.animate({
                height: height
            }, function() {
                fluctuate($(this));
            });
        }

        $(".bar").each(function(i) {
            fluctuate($(this));
        });
    },

    displayTime:function(){

        // function(){date()}, 

        setInterval(function(){
            date()}, 
        1000);

        function date() {
            var now = new Date(),
                now = now.getHours()+':'+now.getMinutes();
            $('#timeDisplay').html(now);
        }
    }

};

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

$(document).ready(function(){

    weatherAPP.displayTime();

    weatherAPP.generateMap();

    $('.boom').on('click', function(){

        if(mainWrapper.hasClass(animateLeft)){
            weatherAPP.slideToCloseSearch();
        }else{
            weatherAPP.slideToSearch();
        }

    });

    weatherAPP.searchCity();

});
```

The problem that I have is my "lati" and "long" variables values.

The following seems to change often:

```
            lati = places[0].geometry.location.D,
            longi = places[0].geometry.location.k,
```

To get the new lati today I had to change it to:

```
places[0].geometry.viewport.N.N
```

It seems like the geometry object content seems to change often... Is there a way of writing the code so that regardless of the change will always work?

See image for geometry object in the console

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is more simple, check if this work:

```
place = autocomplete.getPlace();

console.log(place.geometry.location.lat());
console.log(place.geometry.location.lng());
```

[JSFiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/3PJ6f/49/)

Comment: I will try but can you explain or tell me why do you think it's better/would work? Thanks

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: autocomplete is not defined

Comment: Alex in your code, "autocomplete" is "searchbox", you must change only the part of "geometry.location.lat/lng".

Comment: The following seems to work: lati = places[0].geometry.location.lat(),
             longi = places[0].geometry.location.lng(),

Comment: I guess by using "lati = places[0].geometry.location.lat()" is more effective than relying on the letters within the object?

Comment: @Alex I do not think that Google developers have write a method difficult to remember such as "D" or "k"... They seem to be the appropriate name will not change! and then just google "geometry.location.lat()", there are others who use these methods (but I have not found the official guide)

Comment: Found what I was looking for: http://blog.endpoint.com/2015/06/google-maps-javascript-api-latlng.html

Comment: Google are likely minifying their data to reduce bandwidth. Relying on the state of this minified data is unwise and unpredictable. As such, using the correct API method (as in @Baro 's) answer is the way forward.